# DEPRECATION: Controller#needs is deprecated, please use Ember.inject.controller() instead

Tags: ember.js

Just updated Ember to v1.13.5, and received this warning:

> DEPRECATION: Controller#needs is deprecated, please use Ember.inject.controller() instead

Can't find the documentation yet on how to write the new syntax. Any suggestions on how to fix this warning would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For some reason it's marked as a private method in the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_controller), in order to see it you ll need to tick the private checkbox.

There are 2 ways to use it, with and without passing a controller name to it

```
App.PostController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  posts: Ember.inject.controller()
});
```

When the name of the controller isn't passed, ember uses the property name to look it up such as `posts: Ember.inject.controller('posts')`.

You will only ever specify the controller name when the property and the controller have different names.

```
App.PostController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  myPosts: Ember.inject.controller('posts')
});
```

Comment: I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/11883) should be merged when the maintainers get the chance ^^

Answer (score 6):

Here is one simple example and [this blog post](http://raytiley.com/posts/the-evolution-of-injecting-services-in-ember/) talks more about the evolution from manual injection to "Ember.inject"

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  flashManager: Ember.inject.controller('flash-message'),

  actions: {
    upVote: function() {
      // Do some voting
      var flashManager = this.get('flashManager');
      flashManager.pushMessage('error', 'Your vote does not count');
    }
  }
}
});
```

Comment: For a nested controller, would you recommend 'admin/product' or 'admin.product' as the name property? Both seem to work in Ember 1.13, not sure which is more conventional.

Comment: Word on the street is that "slashes" are preferred as they show the path to the file in question on the file system.